# Linux : How to move a file from one folder to another folder in a remote machine without logging in

Tags: linux, bash, command, move, scp

I want to move a file from one folder to another inside my remote machine without doing ssh (logging into the machine). Ex. like with "SCP" we can store a file into our remote machine without logging in, I want some technique for **moving the file**.

**Practical Scenario :**

I am trying to sent a file to 100 machines. I will "SCP" the file to the "Uploads" directory of all the remote machines from my local server, then I need to copy the file to "Back_up" directory. I can not send the file directly to "Back_up" directory again, as large file transfer to remote host will consume more time and I need to delete the file  after some time from "Uploads" after being sure that that file exists inside "Back_up". So if I can somehow move the file from "Uploads" to "Back_up" the whole issue will be solved.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send a command to be remotely executed with ssh

```
ssh user@host 'mv a b'
```